# jq add or update a value with multiple --arg

Tags: json, jq

I have `file.json` in the structure of:

```
{
  "connections": {}
}
```

I want to update the connections object with variables `$1` and `$2`. I'm trying:

```
jq --arg ssid "$1" --arg pass "$2" '.connections.$ssid = "$pass"' file.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json file.json
```

But I'm getting back `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.connections.$ssid = "$pass"`

I'm expecting `script.sh value key` to produce:

```
{
  "connections": {key:"value"}
}
```

How can I update the object with multiple arguments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use [`[]` indexing](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#GenericObjectIndex:.[%3Cstring%3E]) to use variables (or anything non-literal) as the key:

```
jq --arg ssid abc --arg pass 123 '.connections[$ssid] = $pass' < file.json
{
  "connections": {
    "abc": "123"
  }
}
```

Here `[$ssid]` indexes into `.connections` with the value of `$ssid` as the key. The error was at "`.$`", which is a syntax error, rather than to do with multiple variables.

[Variables](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier%7C...) aren't substituted in directly as strings in the way they might be in a shell script, but are actual named lexical bindings that have to be used in expression context. The index could be a more complex expression: `.connections[$ssid + "X"] = $pass` would put an X on the end first and use that as the key.